# Why doesn't post increment on a pointer work "correctly" when passed an an argument to sscanf

Tags: c++, scanf, increment, post-increment

When I use post increment on the pointer to the string we are scanning from when calling sscanf, scanf actually operates on the incremented value, not the value before the increment as I would expect.

This code:

```
for (int i=0;i<=3;++i)
{
    unsigned val;
    sscanf(abyte+=2,"%2x", &val);
    eeprom_cache[i] = val;
}
```

when abyte points to "aabbccdd" this coee ends up putting 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd and 0x00 into val.  By my understanding of postincrement, it should start at aa.

if I change the code to:

```
for (int i=0;i<=3;++i)
{
    unsigned val;
    sscanf(abyte,"%2x", &val);
    abyte+=2;
    eeprom_cache[i] = val;
}
```

it works.

Why?  Isn't that the whole post of post increment?

I'm running on Windows 10, VS2010, C++.

Comment: `+=` is not post-increment.

Comment: what is `abyte` ? is it a `char*` ?

Comment: `+=` means add somehting to whatever is in the left hand side. It's *not* post-increment.

Answer (score 2):

`abyte += 2` is not post-increment, it's an assignment-operator expression that evaluates immediately and returns the value assigned.

`abyte++` is post increment.  But that will only increment by one, so it's not what you want.  Your second version of the loop is the right way to do it.

Comment: Wow, that was stupid.  This is what happens when we get rusty.